# Error with type written avro file in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I have a Spark streaming application with Kinesis. Events are entered in this format:

```
{
    "timestamp": 0,
    "operation": "I",
    "tableName": "ESQ1.TABLA1",
    "numColumns": 4,
    "values": ["value1", 5645, 2009, 1.23, 2.23, true, "2009-10-02 16:52:30", "2009-10-02 16:52:30"],
    "hash": "hjkfsdh879384394sdkldjf"
}
```

but the object of values can vary. Depending on the source of the event it can have more fields.

TI need to write these events to Avro files, for that I consult a metadata table and created the scheme for each of the data sources...e.g.:

```
root
     |-- COD_HABIT: string (nullable = true)
     |-- COD_TARIFA: integer (nullable = true)
     |-- FEC_CREACION: integer (nullable = true)
     |-- IND_TIPO: double (nullable = true)
     |-- SEQ_RESERVA: double (nullable = true)
     |-- USU_CREACION: boolean (nullable = true)
     |-- CDR_LOAD_TIMESTAMP: string (nullable = true)
     |-- CDR_EXTRACTION_TIMESTAMP: string (nullable = true)
```

The other thing I have to do is deserialize the event. **Here is the problem:**

```
object EventStream {

  def fromJson(arrayByte: Array[Byte]): EventStream = {
    implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
    val string = new String(arrayByte, "UTF-8")
    println(string)
    val parsed = parse(string)
    parsed.extract[EventStream]
  }
}
case class EventStream(timestamp: String, operation: String, tableName:   String, values: List[String], hash: String)
```

If I do everything as string after giving problems when I dataframe because the types of values do not match with the scheme.

```
 sqlContext.createDataFrame(minRDD, minRDDSchema)
            .write
            .mode(SaveMode.Append)
            .avro("s3n://" + config.bucket + "/" + dynamoSchema.entity_key + "/" + dynamoSchema.schema_hash + "/" + timeNowForPath() + "/")

 minRDD.first()
 [value1, 5645, 2009, 1.23, 2.23, true, 2009-10-02 16:52:30, 2009-10-02 16:52:30]
```

the error is a java.lang.ClassCastException:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

I can not do something because it is so efficient is through the list of values and make a asInstanceOf...

Any ideas...?

Comment: Where does the exception occur?

Comment: In the above code when going to write s3

Comment: How about a local file, like `.avro("/tmp/output")`. Did that work?

Comment: no ... the problem is when deserializing the list of values in the json being done as a string and not all fields are string in the schema

Comment: It is not very useful design in the first place. Lift JSON (it is Lift, isn't it?) doesn't handle heterogeneous lists without type hints. Even if you go around this and pattern match over `JArray` you still have to convert it to `struct` since Spark DataFrame doesn't support heterogeneous collections. Why not store values as a document (key-value pairs) in the first place?